# One Less Network Call For EF Core Deletes

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core

The author of [this article](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/more-efficient-deletes-with-entity-framework-core) claimed that to delete an entity, it isn't necessary to receive that entity once and then delete it with another query:

```
{
var person = await db.Persons.FindAsync(id); // 1 database call
if (person is not null) db.Remove(person);
await db.SaveChangesAsync(); // 1 database call

// 2 total database calls
}
```

But it is better to refer to the database only once with the following method to delete an entity.

```
try
{
    var person = db.Persons.Attach(new Person { Id = id });
    person.State = EntityState.Deleted;
    await db.SaveChangesAsync(); // 1 database call
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    // will happen if record no longer exists
}
```

Well, that seems to be, the only problem that may arise with this method is the chance that another process or client request has already deleted the record, Of course, he has admitted that this problem can be handled with `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`, However, Is this the best way to delete an entity from database? Is it really possible to trust this method in all cases, and does it not cause any other problems?

I am currently using .Net6 and earlier in my project.

Comment: EF Core 7 has `ExecuteDelete`.

Comment: I know, However, I am currently using .Net6 and earlier in my old projects, and I can't upgrade right now all of them.

Comment: EF Core 7 is targeted to .NET 6